# IBM MQ - Wake up a MQ Channel

Tags: sleep, ibm-mq

I was wondering if you can help me solve the following problem.

After a while of no-messages being received by the Queue Manager, the Queue Manager goes to 'sleep' and unless you use IBM WebSphere Explorer to 'start the queue' using the command.

On the other hand, if you send a message and expect a response, it will say - Cannot connect.
Then, if you send the same message again, expecting the response, I've noticed the Queue Manager wakes-up.

So to summarize, my question is:

Does anyone know of a command to 'wake-up' the Queue Manager, before sending an actual message(as above).

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

IBM MQ Queue manager does not go to `sleep`. If queue manager is running, then it's awake and is no "wake up". There must be some reason because of which queue manager might have shutdown. Check logs in "errors" folder.

Can you please explain what you mean by 'start the queue'? because there is nothing like that. There is start `queue manager`.

What MQ reason code are you getting when it says "cannot connect".

Comment: Sorry, to be specific, I meant that the Channel(s) goto sleep: If you open IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer. Click on Queue Managers -> "the Queue Name" -> Channels: In the window on the right under "Overall Channel Status" it says "Stopped". When you Rick-Click on the Channel Name there is an option to 'Start' (if not already started) and 'Stop' (if already running). So again, is there a command in the APIs to start the channels?

Comment: Is the channel of type Server Connection (SVRCONN)? When an application is not connected to queue manager, a SVRCONN type channel will be in 'Inactive' state and changes automatically to 'Running' state when an application connects.

Comment: Hi, yes it is a SVRCONN channel. I am seeing that it changes to 'Running' state when a message is sent to the Queue Manager (and thus down the channel) and not; as you say, when the application connects. The application 'connects' to the Queue Manager, not to the channel.

Comment: An MQ client application connects to a queue manager (in client mode) over an MQ Channel.  The client application uses a CLNTCONN and the queue manager must have a same-named SVRCONN channel for the connection to happen.  When the client application disconnects, the SVRCONN channel will go into an "inactive" state (when the connection count hits zero).  When the client application connects again, the SVRCONN channel will automatically go from "inactive" state to a "Running" state.  There is nothing for you to do unless someone or something manually issued a stop channel command.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So I spoke to the admin of the MQ Service and there is a parameter they can set (some timeout I think) that sets it to 0 so it never 'sleeps'.

This will fix the problem.